# Limit user access to api calls?

Tags: rest, api, authorization

I am creating a rest api to be the backend for a messaging app. I want a user to only have access to their own data. For example user1 can call /users/user1 but not /users/user2. How would I go about doing this.

So first the user will login and be authenticated via their username and password. But where do I go from here? I was thinking of storing a token with the users data so when they access it I can verify that the pair matches but there must be a better way to do this. Do I need to restructure my api?

Comment: What language and server framework are you using for your rest api?

Comment: @Mark Python with flask and flask-restplus

Answer (score 0):

After the user logs into the system, you should provide them a token or initialize a session for that user. In each consecutive call, the user should send the token to the API. As long as the token/session is alive user should be able to call the API.

You should have a way to verify the user token in the backend for each API call. A very popular way of doing this is to use JWT(JSON Web Tokens) based authentication. 
See here for an example using python and flask: https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/

Once you verify the user, you should parse the user id to the database query in order to filter out the data for that user.

Even though I don't understand your full use case, it seems like you need to restructure your API calls as well. You should not provide API calls per user. What happens when the numbers of users increase in your system dynamically?

So you should either accept user id as a parameter or you should let the JWT authenticator take care of it.

Example REST API call would be

```
GET /user/data?userId=1234
```